# Bulk methods with ruby MongoDB API

Tags: ruby, mongodb

This is example from Mongo shell methods:

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "P" } ).upsert().updateOne(
   {
   item: "TBD",
   points: 0,
   inStock: true,
   status: "I"
   }
  );
bulk.execute();
```

How can I do that with ruby MongoDB API?

Comment: You should be using [`bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#bulk_write-instance_method) in order to keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: There is examples of basic bulk_write() operations (insert_one, update_one, etc...) in ruby MongoDB API documentation but I don't know how to integrate those find and upsert methods to update_one in Ruby..

Comment: JavaScript uses `:` in Objects, and Ruby uses `=>` instead. What else is there to learn?